# How to access function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have such JavaScript code:

```
<script>
function Foo() { alert('Foo'); }

$.post('file.php', {}, function(data) {
   $('#elem').append(data);
});
</script>

<div id="elem"></div>
```

Example **data**:

```
<script>Foo()</script>
```

Sure, `Foo()` is inaccessible there. How can I grab call it?

Comment: need more context, more info.  As-is all by itself that script works.

Comment: What `data` looks like when it returns from the server?

Comment: By "Example data" I'm guessing the ajax call is returning the script tag with the function call inside it? Are you sure the function call is executed after it has been placed on the page?

Comment: Maybe you should change your `append` to `html`. I've tested here http://jsfiddle.net/QwrtJ/ and it worked forcing the value into `data`. Also check if your server code is not returning it encoded...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

easy answer.  you need to set a variable like so: `var foo = function(){}`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = function(data){
    alert(data);
}

$.post({
    url: 'someurl.aspx',
    success: function(data){
        foo(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide more actual code so we can help?  The above code is just an example of declaring the function and the actual $.post code would def not work... obviously.

Comment: No, you don't need to set foo that way.

Comment: Funny how this is downvoted twice yet marked as the answer.  haters gonna hate.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure

1. jQuery is loaded
2. `#elem` is defined when the return from the ajax call occurs. (*try putting it before the script just to make sure*)
3. Make sure the function `foo` is not defined inside the document ready method of jquery `$(function(){ //FOO should not be defined in here.. });`.

example at http://jsfiddle.net/k7Y55/2/

Answer (score 0):

`foo`  should be accesible if it was defined before you call it.

Also, you should terminate your function calls with a semicolon `;`

```
<script>
  function Foo() { 
    alert('Foo'); 
  }
</script>
```

...

```
<script>
  Foo();
</script>
```

Comment: No, functions doesn't need to end with semicolon

Comment: and javascript doesn't require whitespace either.
it helps you prevent making stupid mistakes though.

Comment: Functions defined like the above don't need a semi-colon.  However function CALLS like `foo();` should end with a semi-colon.  Timothy is correct.

Comment: @BrunoLM: He didn't say it needs to be, he said it *should* be. Even though it is not necessary, it is good practice to end all expressions with semicolons, both for readability, but more importantly, depending on what system/editor you are using, the newline whitespace char needed for javascript to correctly interpret the end of the expression might end up being stripped, which would cause an error.  In this case, it won't happen because it's a single line of code, but in general, it can and does  happen.

Comment: @mark biek: read carefully. i wrote : `you should terminate your function calls with a semicolon`

Comment: @Timothy I'm agreeing with you.  I thought Bruno's implication was regarding function definitions.

Comment: @Crayon Even if I still disagree with you because of performance and other stuff what does it have do to with the question anyway? A comment would be more suitable in this case.

Comment: I stated in my answer that if you define a function as such before calling it, it should be available.


It seems however, that Ockonal has some kind of scope problem, (or maybe a definition problem he's not seeing).

Comment: @BrunoLM: What do you mean about "a comment would be more suitable?"  My statement to you *was* a comment... and are you seriously going to play the performance card on that? Okay, if you really want to.. a character is a character whether it is displayed on the screen or not. \n is still a character, just like ; though \n is usually \r\n for cross-OS compatibility, which makes ; technically the "more efficient" version since it's less bytes.

Comment: @Cray I mean this answer is a comment and doesn't have anything to do with the solution of the question.

Comment: @BrunoLM: I still don't understand what you're going on about.  You made a *comment* on *this* answer: "No, functions doesn't need to end with semicolon", so I respond to *you* with a *comment* on *this* answer, saying that you read the answer wrong and gave more explanation.

Comment: He means my answer might be better suited as a comment.
I do not agree, since i'm trying to convey the fundamentals of define-first, then use.

Comment: @BrunoLm : Maybe a bit late for this, but humor me.
Exactly what kind of impact does leaving a couple of semicolons out have? (performance-wise)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  dataType: "script",
  success: function(data){
    $('#elem').append(data);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that will still not work if #elem isn't defined before `success` is called.
the ajax call must happen *after* #elem is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you `append("<script>Foo()</script>")`, the `/` breaks the string.
Just add the `\` char, like this: `append("<script>Foo()<\/script>")`.

Yes, I know that this string is an ajax return in your case.
So, just return `"<script>Foo()<\/script>"` from server-side.

Take a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/qps2q/